# How to find logarithm of a 6 digit from 4 digit logarithm table?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have a log table of 4 digit and I know how to find log of a 4 digit number. But is it possible to find log a 6 digit number? I have searched a lot about it on net but everywhere I am encountering example for only 4 digit number.
The only exception is  Chambers Educational Course, which are giving 7 figure tables. So this brings me to the main question: "Is it possible to find log of 83407 (example form the book) using a 4 digit log table?"

Comment: Use $\log(a\times b) = \log(a) + \log(b)$ to make your question of the log of a larger number into the question of the logs of two smaller numbers.  If you need to, then you can just estimate rather than factoring properly.

Comment: Also, for what its worth... $83407$ is not a six-digit number... it is a *five* digit number.  It does happen to be prime, so we wouldn't have been able to factor exactly but we could estimate it as $\log(83407) \approxeq \log(834)+\log(100)$, but to be fair using a table is estimation and non-exact already, so little additional harm can be done from this.

Comment: I suppose this would have been an interesting problem in the 1950s, but since the advent of calculators, why are you even asking this question?

Comment: Just out of curiosity...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork you don't carry a [slide rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_rule) around with you anymore?

Comment: Log tables often have little mystery numbers in the margins of each page that are intended to be an aid to linear interpolation for the numbers on that page. Does yours have these?  Have you seen [What are these numbers in a logarithmic table?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224713/what-are-these-numbers-in-a-logarithmic-table)?

Comment: More generally, do you know how to do interpolation? For large $x$, $\log x$ is quite flat, so linear interpolation between known values is quite accurate.

Comment: In the sense of MjD you may do:
$\log 83407 = \log 10 + \log 8340.7$ and now interpolate linearly  between $\log 8340$ and $\log 8341$.